# Dot Product of Block Matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors

How to multiply two matrices, which elements themselves are matrices? The following works but is there a more elegant way?

```
(A = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3, 2, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Matrix A]

```
(B = Array[Subscript[b, ##] &, {3, 1, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Matrix B]

```
dotdot[A_, B_] := Table[Sum[A[[i, l]].B[[l, j]], {l, Dimensions[A][[2]]}], {i, Dimensions[A][[1]]}, {j, Dimensions[B][[2]]}];
dotdot[A, B] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Matrix AB]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to turn them into ordinary matrices, take the dot product, and then `ArrayReshape` them into the form you want.

```
Af = ArrayFlatten[A];
Bf = Flatten[B];

ArrayReshape[Af.Bf, {3, 1, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Just to check:

```
ArrayReshape[Af.Bf, {3, 1, 2}] == dotdot[A, B]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) instead:

```
r1 = dotdot[A, B];
r2 = TensorTranspose[
    TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{2, 5}, {4, 7}}],
    {1, 3, 2}
];

r1 === r2
```

> True

**Comparison**

One advantage of the [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) approach is that if `A` and `B` are sparse arrays, then the result is also a sparse array. This is not true for the other answers. For example:

```
A=SparseArray @ RandomChoice[{.9,.1}->{0,1}, {5, 6, 7, 8}];
B=SparseArray @ RandomChoice[{.9,.1}->{0,1}, {6, 9, 8}];

r1 = dotdot[A, B];
r2 = TensorTranspose[
    TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{2, 5}, {4, 7}}],
    {1, 3, 2}
];

Normal[r1] === Normal[r2]
Head /@ {r1, r2}
```

> True
>
> {List, SparseArray}

*I didn't include @aardvark2012's answer because ArrayReshape apparently doesn't work with sparse arrays anyway*

Comment: great, you guessed my next question: how to do the same with SparseArray..